# How to display information for a specific value?

Tags: angular, typescript

On this page, I display a specific user to edit their information `/users/524.json`. How can I display working days from another table on the same page. I've laid out most of the code just in case. On "StackBlitz" sorry but deploy there I can't. Mostly I have somewhere here the problem " `loadWorkingDays`". Please look and tell me what to fix.

html:

```
<div class="card">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Working Days</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let workingDay of filteredWorkingDays" >
          <td>{{workingDay.date}}</td>                             
       </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

ts:

```
  ...
  users: Array<User>;
  workingDays: Array<WorkingDay>;
  id: number;
  routeId: any;
  returnUrl: string;
  public errorMsg;
  filteredWorkingDays  =[];

  constructor(
    private authTokenService: Angular2TokenService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private servUser: UserService,
    private servWorkingDay: WorkingDayService,
  ) {
    this.workingDays = new Array<WorkingDay>();
    this.users = new Array<User>();
  }

  @Input() workingDay: WorkingDay;
  @Input() user: User;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadWorkingDays();
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/users';
    this.routeId = this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
      }
    )
    let userRequest = this.route.params
      .flatMap((params: Params) =>
        this.servUser.getUser(+params['id']));
    userRequest.subscribe(response => this.user = response.json(), error => this.errorMsg = error);
  }

   private loadWorkingDays() {
        let filteredWorkingDays = this.workingDays;
        if (this.servWorkingDay) {
          this.servWorkingDay.getWorkingDays().subscribe(workingDay => this.workingDays = workingDay);
            }
        this.filteredWorkingDays = this.workingDays.filter((workingDay) => workingDay.w_user_id == this.user.user_id);

      }
 ...
```

Comment: `let filteredWorkingDays = this.workingDays;`.. What is the purpose of this assignment? At that point `this.workingDays` is still an empty array.

Comment: @callback on this can be not to pay attention I tried to do anything to earned)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this line

`this.filteredWorkingDays = this.workingDays.filter((workingDay) => workingDay.w_user_id == this.user.user_id);`

should also be in the subscribe callback. otherwise, `filteredWorkingDays` will always be undefined since `workingDays` is undefined at the moment you assign it.

Your function should look like:

```
private loadWorkingDays() {
    let filteredWorkingDays;
    if (this.servWorkingDay) {
        this.servWorkingDay.getWorkingDays().subscribe(workingDay => {
            this.workingDays = workingDay;
            this.filteredWorkingDays = this.workingDays.filter((workingDay) => workingDay.w_user_id == this.user.user_id);
        });
    }
}
```